# React useState crashes

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement a simple menu with `ASP.net core 2.1`, `Typescript 3.2.1`, `material-ui 3.8.3` and `React 16.7.0`. When I run the application it crashes on the line with `useState` with the error `TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.useState is not a function`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton'
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu'

function TopbarMenu(props: any) {
    const { classes } = props
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null); // Crashes here. Compiled line becomes: var _React$useState = react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.useState(null),

    function handleClick(event: any) {
        console.log(event.currentTarget)
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    }

    function handleClose() {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <IconButton onClick={handleClick} className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
                <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Menu id="simple-menu" anchorEl={anchorEl} open={Boolean(anchorEl)} onClose={handleClose}>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClick}><Link to={'/orderform'}>Orderform</Link></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClick}><Link to={'/products'}>Products</Link></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClick}><Link to={'/customers'}>Customers</Link></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClick}><Link to={'/licenses'}>Expiring Licenses</Link></MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </div>
    );
}

const styles = {
    menuButton: {
        marginLeft: -12,
        marginRight: 20,
    },
}

export default withStyles(styles)(TopbarMenu)
```

What am I missing here?

I'm following material-ui's documentation found here: https://material-ui.com/demos/menus/#simple-menu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**

**Side notes**:
Always use Hooks at the top level of your React function.

See [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation)

```
    //Not that bad
    const { classes } = props
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
```

```
    //Preferably (in my opinion)
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null); 
    const { classes } = props
```

**Answer**

React Hooks are available from React 16.7.0-alpha, [reactconf2018](https://youtu.be/dpw9EHDh2bM?t=3340). Now currently available in [React v16.8.0-alpha.0.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Comment: Thank you. I just read the react changelog and saw that hooks weren't released in 16.7.0

Comment: It seems like you misunderstood the docs. They should always be at the top level and have the same call order. I don't see it mentioning that they "should come first". Maybe they removed that statement later on?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<Element|null>(null);
```